# Why is the escape sequence \t (tab) not working?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, escaping

this is my code:

```
print('Yes, my name is\tSwayam')                           # tab
print('Yes, my name is\tSwayam'.expandtabs(tabsize = 11))
```

this is the output in terminal:

```
Yes, my name is Swayam
Yes, my name is       Swayam
```

software used is 'vs code'

what should I do to make `\t` work?

I wanted a tab after 'is' in first line which is 4 spaces (i guess) and 11 spaces in second line but it's only 7 spaces

Comment: Looks fine to me. What would you expect the code to do?

Comment: I wanted a tab after 'is' in first line which is 4 spaces and 11 spaces in second line but it's only 7 spaces

Comment: Tabs are not a fixed number of spaces, they are horizontal positions.

Answer (score 2):

The default tab width is 8. Therefore:

```
print('Yes, my name is\tSwayam')
```

...produces...

```
Yes, my name is Swayam
```

...because only one space is needed to align with the next tab position (16 in this case)

Comment: I wanted a tab after 'is' in first line which is 4 spaces (i guess) and 11 spaces in second line but it's only 7 spaces

Comment: @SWAYAMMOHANTY Think of tabs as being columns which are, by default, 8 characters wide. What you seem to want is additional spaces - not tabs. A tab character in a string just "moves" to the next tab position filling spaces as needed. Your code is behaving correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can try inserting a space before `\t`,
like this:

```
print('Yes, my name is \tSwayam') 
print('Yes, my name is\tSwayam')
```

This is the terminal output:

```
Yes, my name is         Swayam
Yes, my name is Swayam
```

Hope this helps you.